# socket.io не работает на хостинге

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

не могу настроить работу socket.io на домене https://epick.top
Вот код:

**server.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');

const ssl = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/httpd-cert/www.epick.top_2020-08-11-14-56_14.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/httpd-cert/www.epick.top_2020-08-11-14-56_14.key')
};


var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(ssl, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://epick.top/"); 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Далее, на странице сайта я подключаю клиентский socket.io:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
```

И просто пытаюсь подключиться:

```
const socket = io('https://epick.top:3000');
    
socket.on('connection', (socket) => {
    alert('connection');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

В консоли ([скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te3sB.jpg)) много сообщений о том, что есть попытка подключения по `http`, хотя сам сайт загружен по `https`.

Если же посмотреть код страницы, то можно увидеть что он немного отличается от представленого вами

[image]

Соотвественно, нужно на 803-ей строке заменить протокол на `https`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да. отличается, так как я пытался и http и с https - и так и так не работает. Сейчас заменю.

Comment: теперь в консоли: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: На данная момент я не наблюдаю данной проблемы на сайте. Если решили, можете написать что именно было сделано?

Comment: Да, решил самостоятельно. Не знаю что конкретно помогло, но я подключил модуль https вместо http и к сертификатам добавил .toString()